# How to update an existing object in a many to many relationship (.Net 5)

Tags: .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I have been using the .Net 5 and EF Core 5 for a small web app. Given EF Core 5 supports many - many out of the box there is no need for a joining table.

I've run into an issue when updating a object that already exists in the DB. For my app I have Athletes and Parents which have the many - many relationship.

```
public class Athlete
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public StateEnum State { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSignedUp {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Postcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public StateEnum State { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSignedUp {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Athlete> Athletes { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to update the existing athlete that has a relation ship with two other parents I get an error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AthleteParent'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.AthleteParent'. The duplicate key value
> is (31, 1)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Athlete>> PostAthlete(Athlete athlete)
{
     _context.Athletes.Update(athlete);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return Ok(athlete));
}
```

From what I can tell when entity tries to update my Athlete it tries to insert new rows into the joining table even though the parents already exist in there. Is there a way to get entity to remove any records when the relationship is updated? Or is there a way to tell entity to take update the joining table to match the Athlete object that is passed in?

Comment: You'd think that when microsoft released many-many support theyd have such basic things working as update

Comment: I didn't look at many to many in EF core 5 yet, but probably it's the same thing as ever with many to many in EF. You have to figure out yourself which relationships are new or should be deleted. EF doesn't know the existing relationships in this disconnected scenario. Usually deleting all old relationships and inserting the current ones works well enough.

Comment: Hmm, so in that case I'd be better of not using the auto joining table then right? Cos at the moment I can't access it as entity should be handling it all by default. 

I guess if I maintain the AthletesParents table my self then it'd be easy to remove / add records as needed.

Comment: IMO, yes. I've never liked these many to many associations without an explicit junction class. Not only because of the frictions mentioned here but mainly because they're not expressive enough to cover the *concept* of an association class.

Comment: @Liam Junction table is purely a database-centric concept. Conceptually speaking, your domain model shouldn't even be aware of that entity, and you yourself are not supposed to manipulate it. When you are using an ORM (EF Core), its the ORM's responsibility to deal with that. That is the very reason the new transparent configuration is finally introduced in EF 5.0.

Comment: @Liam To implement many-to-many update in a disconnected scenario without dealing with a junction table, check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943428/446519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a simple example like this:

```
public class Foo {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

You can call `clear()` on a tracked instance of `Foo`, and then re-add the `Bar` instances that you want assigned. I've found this is a nice way to avoid the constraint exception - much easier than manually trying to figure out what Bars have changed.

```
var foo = context.Foos.Include(x => x.Bars).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == someGuid);
foo.Bars.Clear();
foo.Bars.Add(bar1);
foo.Bars.Add(bar2);
...
context.Update(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about the Clear() function but sure beats the solution I have been using :).

Answer (score 0):

In my Blazor app, when I used this solution, I got a

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type '' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'
```

I found that if I issued a SaveChanges() after the Clear() and generated a new clean context, my issue was resolved.

```
context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext()
var foo = context.Foos.Include(x => x.Bars).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == someGuid);
foo.Bars.Clear();
context.SaveChanges();
context.Dispose();

context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
var foo = context.Foos.Include(x => x.Bars).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == someGuid);
foo.Bars.Add(bar1);
foo.Bars.Add(bar2);
context.SaveChanges();
```