# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_XY'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.XY'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Using EF Core, I have a `Zone` that can have multiple `Sol` (soils), same `Sol` can be attached to multiple `Zone`:

```
public class Sol
{
    // ...  
    public ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; } = new List<Zone>();
}

public class Zone
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<Sol> Sols { get; set; } = new List<Sol>();        
}

public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Zone> builder)
{
    // ...
    builder
        .HasMany(p => p.Sols)
        .WithMany(p => p.Zones);                
}
```

When adding my Sols to a Zone however I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SolZone'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SolZone'. The duplicate key value is (1, 2).

Some details of implementation:

In my controller, when retrieving the object I do

```
public override async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [FromQuery] bool fullView)
{
    var currentZone = _repository.SingleOrDefault(new GetZoneWithPaysAndSolsSpecification(id));
```

where

```
public class GetZoneWithPaysAndSolsSpecification : Specification<Zone>
{
    public GetZoneWithPaysAndSolsSpecification(int zoneId)
    {
        Query.Where(p => p.Id == zoneId);
        Query.Include(p => p.Pays);
        Query.Include(p => p.Sols);
    }
}
```

before updating the object, I convert my ZoneDTO to Zone and then add it to the database:

```
protected override void BeforeUpdate(Zone zone, ZoneDTO sourceDto)
{
    zone.Sols.Clear();

    foreach (var solId in sourceDto.SolIds)
    {
        var sol = _repository.GetById<Sol>(solId);
        zone.Sols.Add(sol);
    }

    base.BeforeUpdate(zone, sourceDto);
}
```

I use the base controller, that uses the `BeforeUpdate`, like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Edit(TDto dto)
{
    try
    {
        var entity = FromDto(dto);
        BeforeUpdate(entity, dto);
        await _repository.UpdateAsync(entity);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "when editing an object after submit");
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

The repository code

```
public Task UpdateAsync<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
{
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I use AutoMapper

```
protected TBussinesModel FromDto(TDto dto)
{
    return _mapper.Map<TBussinesModel>(dto);
}
```

And the mapping is like this

```
CreateMap<Zone, ZoneDTO>()
    .ForMember(p => p.SolIds, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Sols.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray()))
    .ForMember(p => p.SolNoms, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Sols.Select(s => s.Nom).ToArray()))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: From the error message, you insert the duplicate key in the database.

Comment: @Karney. I understand that, thanks. I added some more details in the OP to meybe better clarify the context

Comment: @Serge Could you please share the code of `FromDto` method?

Comment: @atiyar I added the code, not sure if it is relevant to the question, anyway if it hels would be great

Answer (score 1):

When you are mapping from dto to entity, your `FromDto` method is giving you a `Zone` entity whose `Sols` list is not populated with the zone's existing sols. Its an empty list. So, when you are calling -

```
zone.Sols.Clear();
```

its doing nothing, and at database level, the zone still holds its sols. Then when you are re-populating the `Sols` list, you are trying to insert some previously existing `Sol` to the list.

You have to fetch the existing `Zone` along with its `Sols` list from the database, before clearing and repopulating it. How you can do that depends on how your repository is implemented.

On how to update many-to-many entity in EF 5.0, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943428/446519)

**EDIT :**
Try modifying your base controller's `Edit` method as -

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Edit(TDto dto)
{
    try
    {
        var zone = _repository.SingleOrDefault(new GetZoneWithPaysAndSolsSpecification(dto.Id));
        
        zone.Sols.Clear();
        
        foreach (var id in dto.SolIds)
        {
            var sol = _repository.GetById<Sol>(solId);
            zone.Sols.Add(sol);
        }

        await _repository.UpdateAsync(zone);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "when editing an object after submit");
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**Not related to your issue :**
You are fetching one `Sol` a time inside a loop -

```
foreach (var id in dto.SolIds)
{
    var sol = _repository.GetById<Sol>(solId);
    zone.Sols.Add(sol);
}
```

which is not efficient at all. Try something like -

```
var sols = // fetch all the sols from the database
foreach (var id in dto.SolIds)
{
    zone.Sols.Add(sols.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id));
}
```

Comment: @Serge Please check the EDIT section.

Comment: if I do that, I loose all other properties of my DTO that I get from the Request

Comment: @Serge First try this to see if your issue  gets resolved. If it does, then you can update the code from there.

Comment: I tried that but now it says: "System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Zone' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached."

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship between SOL and Zone is a many to many relationship a Separate table containing the primary keys of both the tables will be created.
A table definition is needed for this many to many relationship. Also Try including the UsingEnity to specify the entity used for defining the relationship

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(p => p.SOL)
    .WithMany(p => p.ZONE)
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("SOL_ZONE"));
```

Comment: I didn't specify the table, so it created me the table "SolZone" automatically... is OK for me the default tablename

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have many to many relationship. So you need to set up a new entity with primary key to be composite for mapping and to configure the entities the right way:
(**In EF Core up to and including 3.x, it is necessary to include an entity in the model to represent the join table, and then add navigation properties to either side of the many-to-many relations that point to the join entity instead:**)

```
    public class Sol
    {
        // ...  
        public ICollection<SolZone> SolZones { get; set; } = new List<Zone>();
    }

    public class Zone
    {
        // ...
        public ICollection<SolZone> SolZones { get; set; } = new List<Sol>();        
    }

    public class SolZone
    {
        public int SolId { get; set; }
        public Sol Sol { get; set; }
        public int ZoneId { get; set; }
        public Zone Zone { get; set; }
    }

    // And in the OnModelCreating
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SolZone>().HasKey(sc => new {sc.SolId , sc.ZoneId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<SolZone>()
             .HasOne<Sol>(s => s.Sol)
             .WithMany(sz => sz.SolZones)
             .HasForeignKey(s => s.SolId)`


        modelBuilder.Entity<SolZone>()
             .HasOne<Zone>(z => z.Zone)
             .WithMany(sz => sz.SolZones)
             .HasForeignKey(z => z.ZoneId);
    }
```

The primary key for the join table is a composite key comprising both of the foreign key values. In addition, both sides of the many-to-many relationship are configured using the HasOne, WithMany and HasForeignKey Fluent API methods.

This is sufficient if you want to access Sol Zone data via the Sol or Zone entities. If you want to query SolZone data directly, you should also add a DbSet for it:

```
public DbSet<SolZone> SolZones { get; set; }
```

You can look up different relationships in EF Core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Comment: so I need to really write all the datatables structure manually each linked table, it creates a mess in the business code... it becames really the database objects, not business anymore

Comment: by the way, I use latest EF 5, maybe is managed differently there?

Comment: Well "EF Core 5.0 supports many-to-many relationships without explicitly mapping the join table." here is a link it is managed differently: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew

Comment: ok, then your solution should be OK for a previous version of ef... EF 5 created the table for me automatically

Comment: yes and there is also no need for you to add configuration in the OnModelCreating.

Comment: it is available in another related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043542/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-fk-xy-on-table-xy-may-cause-cycles-or-mul

Comment: Well I know I state the obvious but Primary key error is on the mapping table of the many to many relationship: 'PK_SolZone', so there must be something wrong with the way your adding and updating your entities for some reason your doing it multiple times. How is your services added as Singleton or Scoped or Transient instances in your start up also in the BeforeUpdate why are you calling the base in the end?