# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_XY' on table 'XY' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have `Affaire` that can have multiple `Zone`

```
public class Affaire {
    // ...
    public ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; };
}

public class Zone {
    // ...
    public ICollection<Affaire> Affaires { get; set; };
}
```

the fluent `Zone` configuration (only on `Zone`) :

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Zone> builder)
{
    // ...
    builder
        .HasMany(p => p.Affaires)
        .WithMany(p => p.Zones)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("Affaire_Zone"));
}
```

Here is my generated migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Affaire_Zone",
    columns: table => new
    {
        AffairesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        ZonesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Affaire_Zone", x => new { x.AffairesId, x.ZonesId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Affaire_Zone_Affaire_AffairesId",
            column: x => x.AffairesId,
            principalTable: "Affaire",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Affaire_Zone_Zone_ZonesId",
            column: x => x.ZonesId,
            principalTable: "Zone",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

The `add-migration` command passes OK. but when I do `update-database` I get the error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Affaire_Zone_Zone_ZonesId' on
> table 'Affaire_Zone' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
> Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
> FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See
> previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved partially by manually updating the Migration code, but when I will do another migration it will remove this code

changed the

```
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

to

```
onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
```

here:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AffaireZone",
    columns: table => new
    {
        AffairesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        ZonesId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AffaireZone", x => new { x.AffairesId, x.ZonesId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AffaireZone_Affaire_AffairesId",
            column: x => x.AffairesId,
            principalTable: "Affaire",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_AffaireZone_Zone_ZonesId",
            column: x => x.ZonesId,
            principalTable: "Zone",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
    });
```